allow-discrete display and height not working as expected
I have a setup where I'm transitioning the height of an element and want to set the display: none when it is closed:


const toggle = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.thing').forEach(
    (el) => el.classList.toggle('closed')
  )
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggle)
.thing {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  transition-property: height, display;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-behavior: allow-discrete;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.thing.closed {
  height: 0;
}

.thing.discrete.closed {
  display: none;
}
<div class="thing">
  I am thing
</div>

<div class="thing discrete">
  I am a discrete thing
</div>

<button>Toggle</button>



In Chrome the demo it works fine going from open to closed and the allow-discrete is working as expected in both directions. However going in the opposite direction it is instantly 50px high and I'm not sure why.

You can  use @starting-style but it will also affect the initial loading of the elements.


const toggle = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.thing').forEach(
    (el) => el.classList.toggle('closed')
  )
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggle)
.thing {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-behavior: allow-discrete;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  @starting-style {
    height: 0;
  }
}

.thing.closed {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
<div class="thing">
  I am thing
</div>

<div class="thing">
  I am another thing
</div>

<button>Toggle</button>



